# SmartPy Percentage/Fee Calculation

Tags: smartpy

I am looking for a reliable way to calculate a percentage.
A simple example would be `100 mutez`, `3%` of this would be `3 mutez`.

Ideally I can get a percentage from tez/mutez etc.

This would be used for taking a fee for example. The intention would be to set a variable like `fee` and then calculate the fee from the available contract balance or balance associated with an address.

Finally taking the set percentage, sending the fee to a fee wallet and the remainder to the user address.

So far attempts using `sp.ediv` and `àbs` all results in floats which causes the following error

`Error: Expression cannot be a float. Got '3.0'`

In the initial example `97 mutez` would be sent to the user and `3 mutez` to the fee wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sp.split_tokens(<your_amount>, <your_pourcentage>, 100)`

Examples:

- `sp.split_tokens(sp.tez(100), 3, 100)` results in sp.tez(3).
- `sp.split_tokens(sp.tez(200), 3, 100)` results in sp.tez(6).